# Google site spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sites

Can we write our front end design and use the google spreadsheet for the back-end for a website?

Thank You

Comment: My first question is: Why would you want to do that? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: ill be actually building a site... for which can i use google site's spreadsheet  for  the backend?

Comment: You mean use it as data storage? Not something you'll actually expose to the user? Wouldn't you get more flexibility from a database?

Comment: i don want to create a database for this.So i wanted to use google spreadsheet as my datastorage which is pretty easy for me.Is there a possibility to such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) might also be a good option for you. You can host your code on the Google servers (all written in JavaScript) with easy access to all the spreadsheet and docs APIs. You can see a lot of [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles) on the site.

Another even simpler option might be [Google Forms](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/forms/) - if you are just trying to gather some data and record it in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably already found an answer or a workaround, but here is an example from Google.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/storing_data_spreadsheets